# mysql Data truncation error

Tags: mysql

I tried this query in **mySql**

```
update myTable set myColumn = 'USER'||id;
```

I get this error

error Code: 0, SQL State: 22001]  Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'USER'

The same query works in oracle and db2

Comment: what is the use of 'USER'||id?

Comment: Datatype of `myColumn` is `DOUBLE`? and it cannot _parse_ 'USER' into it. .

Comment: || a concatenating symbol for Oracle queries not for mysql.in mysql it is Logical OR operator

Comment: You want to truncate the table

Comment: i just have to use concat,
concat('USER', id)

Comment: you may have to change the column type. Double column cannot store strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for string concatenation instead of the oracle operator `||`:

```
update myTable 
set myColumn = CONCAT('USER' , id);
```

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77e95/1)